# Knapsack Problem: Find Top-K Lower Profit Solutions

Tags: python, optimization, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

In the classic 0-1 knapsack problem, I am using the following (dynamic programming) algorithm to construct a "dp table":

```
def knapsack(weights, values, capacity):
    n = len(weights)
    weights = np.concatenate(([0], weights))  # Prepend a zero
    values = np.concatenate(([0], values))    # Prepend a zero
    
    table = np.zeros((n+1, capacity+1), dtype=np.int64)  # The first row/column are zeros
    for i in range(n+1):
        for w in range(capacity+1):
            if i == 0 or w == 0:
                table[i, w] = 0
            elif weights[i] <= w:
                table[i, w] = max(
                    table[i-1, w-weights[i]] + values[i],
                    table[i-1, w]
                )
            else:
                table[i, w] = table[i-1, w]
    return table
```

Then, by traversing the table using the following code, I am then able identify the items that make up the optimal solution:

```
def get_items(weights, capacity, table):
    items = []
    i = len(weights)
    j = capacity
    weights = np.concatenate(([0], weights))  # Prepend a zero
    table_copy = table.copy()
    while i > 0 and j > 0:
        if table_copy[i, j] == table_copy[i-1, j]:
            pass  # Item is excluded
        else:
            items.append(i-1)  # Item is included, fix shifted index due to prepending zero
            j = j - weights[i]
        i = i-1
    return items
```

This is great for finding the items that make up the single optimal solution (i.e., highest total summed value). However, I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve, say, the top-3 or top-5 solutions from this table that has a total weight that is less than or equal to the maximum capacity.

For example, the top-3 solutions for the following input would be:

```
weights = [1,  2,  3, 2, 2]
values =  [6, 10, 12, 6, 5]
capacity = 5

# with corresponding "dp table"
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6],
       [ 0,  6, 10, 16, 16, 16],
       [ 0,  6, 10, 16, 18, 22],
       [ 0,  6, 10, 16, 18, 22]])
```

| Total Summed Value | Items (Zero-based Index) |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | 1, 2 |
| 22 | 0, 1, 3 |
| 21 | 0, 1, 4 |

Note that there is a tie for both first place and so we'd truncate the solutions after the first 3 rows (though, getting all ties is preferred if possible). Is there an efficient way to obtain the top-k solutions from the "dp table"?

Comment: No, that table doesn't have a 21 in it...

Comment: Also, `1,3,4` has total weight of 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd build a richer DP table. For each cell, you store just the total value of just one item set. I'd instead store information of the top k item sets for that cell: both the total value and the indices. Output of the below program:

```
22 [0, 1, 3]
22 [1, 2]
21 [0, 1, 4]
```

And that's the information I store in the final table cell `table[-1][-1]` instead of just your `22`. More precisely, this is the Python data I store there:

```
[(22, [1, 2]), (22, [0, 1, 3]), (21, [0, 1, 4])]
```

If you need it more efficient, I think you could store only the last index of each item set instead of all its indices. But then you have to reconstruct the item sets later, and I'm not in the mood to do that :-)

Full code:

```py
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

def knapsack(weights, values, capacity, k):
    n = len(weights)
    weights = np.concatenate(([0], weights))  # Prepend a zero
    values = np.concatenate(([0], values))    # Prepend a zero
    get_total = itemgetter(0)

    table = np.zeros((n+1, capacity+1), dtype=object)  # The first row/column are zeros
    for i in range(n+1):
        for w in range(capacity+1):
            if i == 0 or w == 0:
                table[i, w] = [(0, [])]
            elif weights[i] <= w:
                table[i, w] = sorted(
                    [
                        (total + values[i], indices + [i-1])
                        for total, indices in table[i-1, w-weights[i]]
                    ] +
                    table[i-1, w],
                    key=get_total,
                    reverse=True
                )[:k]
            else:
                table[i, w] = table[i-1, w]
    return table[-1][-1]

weights = [1,  2,  3, 2, 2]
values =  [6, 10, 12, 6, 5]
capacity = 5
k = 3

top_k = knapsack(weights, values, capacity, k)

for total, indices in top_k:
    print(total, indices)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVTLbpwwFN105a-4UjYgmHZIlCqKyj90kR2yIgcuMy5gu8YE0V_pJpv2o_o1veYxZBpGqSUPHt9zzvU9fvz8bQZ31Orl5Vfnyt3dnw_fZWO0daC6xgwgWlCGlVY3oA1a4bSFGSAdNgd0Di1jBZZQKWFakVdBj_JwdG0Mz6LukL65MCKXboihCu8ZUFOQQo1qgYbj5PyHQsp8zLXKhUNFPQiyPY-XcBgCXMFXiwZVAQJ-oNUjfcp2iT1FPfkCnUp5dNqJmhTW0oJ9yMawE081TuKe0gaBipK1tCgJYyjcYDDVT98wd-MqH44IpbStA6v7T7muu0aBsDhmbUfd0hsKUoEV6oBedLZoCfZr8FWyFeObLEkjTWEPI8GPzgGnCjJJRnKqIwv2MWQ85Gc4rElqNjqTHL6k0L-n1NJhwCJ4g_It25z1LZi8juaNoWQxFVrInLYwgkzuEh5eJHtfRv7KIZPmZe1oW_rdWgTflOEQbc6_FuHxJqTCIT2dlm2IxWe0LaYPtsM3gDC7r_61vcX3bD5bGJuSuM4uZZNfvjO23qKMoHBN_Sb2n2vOTlcEss8xJHQCEgrQ8Jaz5XBR9JZV9HvDmNPm0Q__72ozdmFfvMpUnrFSueAcEk4vz_wALQ_RXw)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong but in the `elif`, `table[i-1, w]` should already be sorted and so I'm thinking that I might be simply able to sort the new item values and indices (without concatenating `table[i-1, w]`). Then, I extract the topk from this list and the already pre-sorted `table[i-1, w]` and merge/combine them in order to find the topk. Merging the two should save me from redundant sorting time and the merge step could be done in `O(k)` time (where `k` is the number of topk items).

Comment: @slaw You are correct. But I doubt that that would be faster. Python's Timsort sorting algorithm is not only written in C, but already also only needs O(k) comparisons here, because it detects and merges the two sorted runs. You could sort with `key=operator.itemgetter(0)` (or `key=first` after setting `first = operator.itemgetter(0)` at the very start). That might be faster, as it would only compare the totals, not also the indices in case of ties of totals. Depends on your data. I'll actually add that, as it's simple and clearer.

Comment: @slaw (continuing the above comment) Ok, I've done that modification. As a result, the two subsets with total value 22 have switched places. I assume that's ok, you don't care about order of subsets with equal totals, right?

Comment: Correct. If two sets of items have the same total value then the order of sets do not matter. In my case, my input may contain 1,000-10,000 items to choose from and so the sorting, while still reasonable (~2-3 seconds), could afford to be faster and it would be great to get down below one second.

Comment: @slaw Is the new version faster or slower for your data?

Comment: Unfortunately, the speed is nearly the same :(

Comment: @slaw How long does your original code take for the same input data? And how long do your original and my current code take when you don't use Numpy? Try them with Python lists and Python ints. And are weights, values and capacity NumPy data types or Python data types? Any NumPy data types slow this down, potentially a lot.

Comment: The original (single optimal solution) version takes 0.001 seconds (using numpy arrays as input). While the topk versions take 2.6 seconds and 1.6 seconds for the sorting everything and only sorting the total value, respectively. I will find some time to test with python lists as input.

Comment: @slaw Ok, if yours is that fast, then the NumPy aspect is probably that insignificant. I'd still use lists, though. I guess you might want to do the optimization I mentioned in the answer after all. That is, store only the last index of each item set instead of all its indices. With `sorted([(total + values[i], i-1) for total, _ in table[i-1, w-weights[i]]] + table[i-1, w], ...)`. How long does that take?